# Static assets route issue in KeystoneJS

Tags: express, keystonejs

I'm creating a blog with KeystoneJS and have an issue with the URL for my static assets.

For example, in default.pug, I have a link to `link(type='text/css', rel='stylesheet', href='/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css')`

When I try to get the home page, the given link is correctly fetched, but when I try to access an URL with more parameters like `/blog/category`, KeystoneJS tries to access `/blog/styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css`.

In the configuration, `'static': 'public'` is correctly defined ('styles' is a subfolder of 'public').

I never encountered this issue before and the main difference is that I have implemented `i18n` and have `keystone.pre('routes', i18n.init);` in `index.js`

But it seems that the routing is done before,so I may be missing an obvious configuration point.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was indeed silly.

The link path to static assets was not absolute ('/' missing upfront)...